# Can a pkcs12 file contain multiple certificate chains?

Tags: certificate, pkcs#12

We are able to store one certificate chain in the pkcs12 file. We want to store two certificate chains in one pkcs12 file. Is this possible ? If so, can you explain me how ?
Thanks.